# .NET String Assignment Removes Characters

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Never seen anything like this before.  I'm doing a very simple DataReader value assignment.

```
story.Byline = _r["Byline"].ToString();
```

But the values of `_r["Byline"].ToString()` and `story.Byline` are different after the assignment.  Here's the output from the Immediate window:

```
story.Byline
"Associated Press - FIRST LASTAssociated Press - FIRST LAST"
_r["Byline"].ToString()
"Associated Press - FIRST LAST<br />Associated Press - FIRST LAST"
```

Why is `<br />` being removed?

Comment: What does `story.Byline` look like?

Comment: story.Byline is just a public string.  I copied the output from the immediate window showing the values.

Comment: What type is `_r["Byline"]`? Is it an XML node? Try `_r["Byline"].GetType().Name`. It's *possible* `.ToString()` removes some formatting, but not if the type of `_r["Byline"]` is string.

Comment: Stating the obvious, rom the looks of the first one, it appears it was keeping non-printable characters held within the "Byline" contents, and the ToString() method is set up to show those character (apparently in HTML).  You can see there should be some sort of spacing between LASTAssociated in the first one that isn't displayed.  Can you give us more information on the types you're using so we can look into that more?

Comment: _r is a SqlDataReader.  _r["Byline"].GetType().Name
"String"

Comment: Hmm... and `story.Byline` is a public string, not a property? The last thing to check is that you're printing the value correctly...

Comment: What is the source of the reader? Do you control it? Are you sure that's string, e.h. VARCHAR(X), etc?

Comment: Using [SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) you can determine the actual type.

Comment: I'm retarded.  See my "answer" below.

Comment: Don't beat yourself, happens to everyone. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit embarrassing:

```
public string Byline
{
    get { return !_elements.ContainsKey("Byline") ? "" : (string)_elements["Byline"]; }
    set
    {
        string _buf = Functions.StripTags(value);
        _elements["Byline"] = _buf;
    }
}
```

Incorrect assumptions FTL. Can this question be deleted?

Comment: Edit the original answer instead of posting another "answer". To close forcefully, flag it and ask moderator to close.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `reader["x"].ToString()` you actually calls x' type possibly overridden method `ToString()`.

If you're sure that it's string, use `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("x"))`